# Error getting template classes to work

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a minHeap of my own and i am getting an error related to my templated class

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include"road.h"
#include"region.h"
#include"minHeap.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

//    int numCities;
    int numOldRoads;

    cin >> numOldRoads;

    minHeap<int> roadHeap(numOldRoads);

    roadHeap.push(1);
    roadHeap.push(4);
    roadHeap.push(5);
    roadHeap.push(2);
    roadHeap.push(7);
    roadHeap.push(6);
    roadHeap.push(3);
    roadHeap.push(9);
    roadHeap.push(8);

    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i<numOldRoads; i++){
        temp = roadHeap.top();
        roadHeap.pop();
        cout << temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef MIN_HEAP
#define MIN_HEAP

template<class T>
class minHeap{

public:
    minHeap(int);
    void push(T);
    void pop();
    T top();
    void doubleHeapCap();
    bool isEmpty();

private:
    T *heap;
    int heapSize;
    int capacity;

};

#endif
```

Here is the implementation of the minHeap (also in the header because it was giving me errors otherwise):

```
#include"minHeap.h"

template<class T>
minHeap<T>::minHeap(int theCapacity = 10){

    if(theCapacity < 1) throw "Capacity must be >=1.";
    capacity = theCapacity;
    heapSize = 0;
    heap = new T[capacity + 1]; //heap [0] is not used

}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::push(const T& e){
//inserts e into min heap
    if(heapSize == capacity){ //doubles capacity if Heap is too small
        minHeap.doubleHeapCap;
        capacity *=2;
    }

    int currentNode == ++heapSize;

    while(currentNode != 1 && heap[currentNode/2] > e){
        //bubble up node
        heap[currentNode] = heap[currentNode/2]; //moves parent down
        currentNode /= 2; //moves current node
    }

    heap[currentNode] = e;

}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::pop(){
//Deletes smallest element from heap and restructures heap
    if(isEmpty()) throw "Heap is empty. Cannot delete.";

    //deelt smallest element
    heap[1].~T();

    //remove last element from heap
    T lastE = heap[heapSize--];

    //trick down to restructure heap
    int currentNode = 1; //root of heap
    int child = 2; // first child of heap

    while(child <= heapSize){

        //set child to smaller child of currentNode
        if(child < heapSize && heap[child] > heap[child+1]) child++;

        //can we put lastE in currenNode?
        if(lastE >= heap[child]) break; //yes we can

        //no we can't, Obama
        heap[currentNode] = heap[child]; //move child up
        currentNode = child; child *= 2; // move a level down
    }

    //after you finally find one, place the node in the corrent position
    heap[currentNode] = lastE;
}

template<class T>
bool minHeap<T>::isEmpty(){
//says whether or not hear is empty
    if(heapSize == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::doubleHeapCap(){

    int currentcapacity = this->capacity;
    int newCapacity = (this->capacity)*2;
    minHeap *temp;
    T *newHeap;

    //create a new heap with twic the size
    newHeap = new T[newCapacity + 1];

    //copy elements over
    for(int i=0; i<=capacity; i++){
        newHeap[i] = this->heap[i];
    }

    //delete the old heap
    temp = heap;
    heap = newHeap;
    newHeap = 0;

    delete[] temp;
}
```

and here is the error:

```
In instantiation of 'void minHeap<T>::doubleHeapCap() [with T = int]':
required from 'void minHeap<T>::push(const T&) [with T = int]'
required from here
error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'minHeap<int>*' in assignment|
warning: unused variable 'currentcapacity' [-Wunused-variable]|
```

I pretty much copied the code from my data structures book and modified it (the book shows an implementation for a Max Heap and i am interested in a min heap).

As you can see all i am trying to do with the main right now is print out the ascending list of integers that i try to push to the min heap.

I think i dont fully understand how to implement template class functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class declaration you have this:

```
T *heap;
```

In `doubleHeapCap` you have this:

```
minHeap *temp;

// code...

temp = heap;
```

If `T` is `int` then you are trying to assign an `int*` (`heap`) to a `minHeap<int>*` (`temp`). Basically, make `temp` into a `T*`, too, and it should work. Or you could just dispense with `temp` altogether and write:

```
std::swap(heap, newHeap);
delete[] newHeap;
```

Comment: wow, such a dumb mistake. Thanks so much! But now it won't compile and gives me the error "ld.exe||cannot open output file bin\Debug\spantree.exe Permission denied|"

I am using code::blocks, do you know why this might be?

Comment: Not terribly familiar with code::blocks unfortunately. Sometimes you can get an error like that if the program is already running when you try to make a change to it, but if you haven't been able to get it to compile that's probably not the case.

Comment: Make sure you closed spantree.exe. Check it in taskmanager if it's still running.

Comment: Ahh i got it to work! Only issue now is that it seems like i didn't actually produce a minheap, because when main.cpp runs and i enter 9 for numOldRoads (so the initial heapsize is 9 it prints out "189567432" and no matter what order i push onto the heap it always seems to output this order....also it appears as though the doubleHeapCapacity is not working either as if i make the initial heap size 5 and i try to push numbers 1 through 9 to it, it only prints out as many numbers as the initial heap size...(but still in the order listed above)

Comment: I can't help you there. Not familiar enough with min and max heaps to understand the difference between what the code should be doing and what it is doing. Maybe someone else can help though :)

Comment: Nevermind, i found a simple typo in my code that was causing it to be all wonky. Thanks so much for the help!